# Как отфильтровать List<T>

Tags: c#

Есть `checkedlistbox`. В нем несколько строк (см. картинка). Также есть `List<T>`, который я хочу отфильтровать по выбранным полям. Сейчас я делаю вот так.

```
foreach (object itemChecked in filterChecked.CheckedItems)
     {
      if (itemChecked.ToString() == "Есть дата первых торгов")
          {
            list.Where(x => x.Pole.ToString() != "");
          }....
     }
```

Можно ли использовать фильтрованный список. Сделать что то типа этого?

```
list.FilteredItems
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, нужно следующее:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> result = list;

foreach (object itemChecked in filterChecked.CheckedItems)
{
    if (itemChecked.ToString() == "Есть дата первых торгов")
    {
        result = result.Where(x => x.Pole.ToString() != "");
    }
    if (itemChecked.ToString() == "Пустая графа вторых торгов")
    {
        result = result.Where(x => x.PoleA.ToString() != "условие");
    }
    if (itemChecked.ToString() == "Движимое имущество")
    {
        result = result.Where(x => x.PoleB.ToString() != "условие");
    }
    // и т. д.
}

var filteredList = result.ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var selectedNames = filterChecked.CheckedItems.Select(x => x.ToString());

var filteredList = list.Where(x => selectedNames.Contains(x.Pole)).ToList();
```

Comment: для каждого selection у меня разные условия

Comment: @Radzhab, передавайте предикат извне.

Answer (score 2):

Можно задать словарь с ключами вида элементов CheckedListBox и значениями в виде фильтрующего условия.

`var source = new Dictionary<string, Func<T, bool>>();`

Заполнить `filterChecked` ключами словаря.

Фильтрация сократится до

```
foreach (var condition in filterChecked.CheckedItems)
{
   list = list.Where(source[condition.ToString()]);
}
```